# Filtering Shipping Options In Woocommerce Based on Date

Tags: ajax, wordpress, session, woocommerce

So, I have a complex Shipping issue I need to solve in woocommerce.

The three things I need to accomplish are:

1. Filter shipping methods based on a datepicker.
2. Reset the WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods') with the lowest available shipping method after filtering based on the above date, AND THEN set the selected method as the $chosen_method.
3. Filter shipping methods based on price.

So, out of these three, #1 and #3 have been simple. I am firing off a $('body').trigger('update_checkout'); when a date is picked, and that sends it to the WC_AJAX->update_order_review method. This then recalculates all the relevant data/methods, and returns the snippets.

However, after filtering my shipping methods and trying to set the cheapest as the first one, AND change the session to match, i'm having problems. It seems that I'm not able to change the session value early enough to be calculated into the correct totals ON THE FIRST TRY. On the second ajax request or page refresh, the session gets set to the correct method.

So, how far up the stack do i need to be to reset that session to get it to listen to that new value on the first try? I need to be able to access the $_POST data, the current available methods, AND be able to reset the session all in one place if possible, but if not, I can run the same code in two places to hopefully get the correct checkout totals and methods set.

Currently, I've been working in cart-shipping.php and i've overwritten one of the functions there to apply some custom filtering, as seen below.
This accomplishes #1 and #3, but I have trouble with the session here. If anybody knows any way to reliably reset that session here, that'd solve all my problems.

```
function woo_new_cart_shipping_html()
{
   global $woocommerce;

   $data_stream = extract_data_from_str( $_POST['post_data'] );

   $packages      = $woocommerce->shipping->get_packages();
   $chosen_method = isset( $woocommerce->session->chosen_shipping_methods[0] ) ? $woocommerce->session->chosen_shipping_methods[0] : '';

   foreach ( $packages as $i => $package )
   {
      $methods = apply_filters( 'woo_filter_available_methods_by_date',       $package['rates'], $data_stream );

       wc_get_template( 'cart/cart-shipping.php', array('package' => $package,
                                             'available_methods' =>           apply_filters( 'woo_sort_shipping_methods_by_cost', $methods ),
                                             'show_package_details' => ( sizeof( $packages ) > 1 ),
                                             'index' => $i,
                                             'chosen_method' =>      apply_filters( 'woo_set_lowest_shipping_method', $chosen_method, $methods, $data_stream ) ) );

   }
}
```